# Discord Bot Online But Does not Respond

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a simple reaction roles bot with a nice anticrash coded with Chalk Package. It was originally made in replit and worked just fine, but I wanted better uptime so I made a repository, loaded it into vscode and compiled it into an executable but I get this error

I tried changing my intents and even going into the discord.js discord server and no one answered me

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const chalk = require("chalk")

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Bot Loaded! Changes Saved!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(
    chalk.white('['),
    chalk.cyan('Express'),
    chalk.white(']'),
    chalk.gray(':'),
    chalk.white('Connected')
  );
});





const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    Partials,
} = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    "Guilds",
    "GuildMessages",
    "DirectMessages",
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

const db = require("quick.db")
let pagination = require('./function/pagination')
// ———————————————[Global Variables]———————————————
client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();
client.cooldowns = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
const Timeout = new Collection();
client.snipes = new Collection()
client.config = require("./botconfig/main.json");
require("./handler")(client);
// Initializing the project.



// ———————————————[Logging Into Client]———————————————
  client.login('');

// ———————————————[Error Handling]———————————————
process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, p) => {
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(
    chalk.white("["),
    chalk.red.bold("AntiCrash"),
    chalk.white("]"),
    chalk.gray(" : "),
    chalk.white.bold("Unhandled Rejection/Catch")
  );
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(reason, p);
});
process.on("uncaughtException", (err, origin) => {
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(
    chalk.white("["),
    chalk.red.bold("AntiCrash"),
    chalk.white("]"),
    chalk.gray(" : "),
    chalk.white.bold("Uncaught Exception/Catch")
  );
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(err, origin);
});
process.on("multipleResolves", (type, promise, reason) => {
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(
    chalk.white("["),
    chalk.red.bold("AntiCrash"),
    chalk.white("]"),
    chalk.gray(" : "),
    chalk.white.bold("Multiple Resolves")
  );
  console.log(chalk.gray("—————————————————————————————————"));
  console.log(type, promise, reason);
});



const Levels = require("discord-xp");

const { mongooseConnectionString } = require("./botconfig/main.json");

Levels.setURL(mongooseConnectionString); 







// ———————————————[Anti Ghost ping]———————————————
let { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
client.on('messageCreate', message => { 
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(!message.guild) return;
const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("+ghostpingdetector")) {
  //=====
 let embedon = new MessageEmbed()
 .setDescription(":green_square: | Turned On GhostPingDetector")
 .setTimestamp()

 //===
  let embedoff = new MessageEmbed()
 .setDescription(":red_square: | Turned Off GhostPingDetector")
 .setTimestamp()
 //====
   if(!args[0]) return message.reply('Do You Want To Turn On or Off ghostpingdetector? Please Type \`w?ghostpingdetector true/false\` or \`on/off\`');
     if(args[0] === "on" || args[0] === "true") {
   message.reply({embeds: [embedon]})
   db.set(`gp_${message.author.id}`, true)
     } else if(args[0] === "off" || args[0] === "false") {
     db.delete(`gp_${message.author.id}`)
     message.reply({embeds: [embedoff]})
   }
   }[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SanR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SanR.png)
})
client.on('messageDelete', message => {
message.mentions.users.forEach(m => {
  if(db.has(`gp_${m.id}`) && m.id !== message.author.id && !message.author.bot){
    
    let emb = new MessageEmbed()
    emb.setTitle('GhostPingDetector')
    emb.setDescription(`<@${m.id}>, You've Been Ghost Pinged.\nUserName: \`${message.author.username}\`\nUserID: \`${message.author.id}\`\nServerName: ${message.guild.name}\nChannel: <#${message.channel.id}>\nContent: ${message.content}`)
    emb.setColor("GREEN")
    emb.setFooter(`Anti-Ghost Ping! woop woop`)
    m.send({embeds: [emb]})
    message.channel.send({embeds: [emb]})
    }
  
})
})

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.id === '1029286082879180832') {
        message.react('✅');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Where's the error?

Comment: it won't allow me to add image

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1025218591651549276/1039962588139757718/image.png

Comment: idk if that link will work for you

Comment: You can copy and paste the error the same way you copy and pasted the code

Comment: —————————————————————————————————
[ AntiCrash ]  :  Multiple Resolves
—————————————————————————————————
resolve Promise {
  {
    url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg',
    shards: 1,
    session_start_limit: {
      total: 1000,
      remaining: 1000,
      reset_after: 0,
      max_concurrency: 1
    }
  }
} undefined
—————————————————————————————————
[ AntiCrash ]  :  Multiple Resolves
—————————————————————————————————
resolve Promise { [] } undefined